# How to generate a unique random integer between 998000 and 998999?

Tags: oracle

I have a two tables.

```
**Table A**
------------
ID | Fst_nm | Lst_nm | AppID

**Table B**
------------
AppID | Fst_nm | Lst_nm
```

I am concerned with the users who exist in Table A but not in Table B, therefore these users do not have any AppID populated in Table A.

I am to first check if the users exist in table B, and if they don't, generate a random 6 digit integer for their AppID in Table A.

These Table A AppIDs need to be unique and between 998000 and 998999.

So my steps are the following:

1. Get all users in Table A with a null value for AppID
2. Check if these users exist in Table B, if they do, copy Table_B.AppID to Table_A.AppID (only way to compare between the tables is to first case match fst_nm and lst_nm then compare)
3. If these users do NOT exist in Table B, generate a random UNIQUE integer 998*** and populate into Table_A.AppID.

I have already built the query for steps 1 and 2, now I am only left with users that exist in Table A but not Table B.

I am using the following to generate my random integer:

```
SELECT round(dbms.random.VALUE(998000,998999) FROM DUAL
```

What I have so far:

```
UPDATE Table_A a
SET a.AppID = (SELECT round(dbms.random.VALUE(998000,998999) 
               FROM DUAL
               WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT AppID
                           FROM Table_A))
WHERE
    a.AppID IS NULL
    AND a.ID IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Table_B
            WHERE
                trim(upper(a.lst_nm)) = trim(upper(b.lst_nm))
            AND trim(upper(a.fst_nm)) = trim(upper(b.fst_nm))
            AND b.fst_nm is not null
            AND b.lst_nm is not null
            );
```

I know this is not correct, since when run, the query updates more rows than necessary. Any tips?

Comment: You can use sequence to update the ID

Comment: @JimMacaulay I am looking into sequence seems like a good solution for generating these numbers i need, but my issue is more that the numbers need to be unique and this process must be repeatable.

Comment: Yes the numbers will always be unique

Comment: @JimMacaulay I know all numbers coming from the sequence will be unique, but how do I ensure the sequence numbers are unique compared to values already entered in the table?

Comment: Take the maximum value of the table and create the sequence with that value+1. If you want i can give you an answer

Comment: @JimMacaulay I actually did as you suggested and it's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for your help

Comment: My pleasure.................

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use MERGE, which will allow you to code INSERT and UPDATE in one SQL statement.  As @JimMacaulay suggested, you could use a sequence for generating the numbers as required.  Example:

Table, data, and sequence

```
create sequence appid_seq start with 998000 ;

create table tableA (
  Fst_nm varchar2( 100 )
, Lst_nm varchar2( 100 )
, AppID number 
) ;

insert into tableA(fst_nm, lst_nm, appid )
select 'first_1', 'last_1', null from dual union all
select 'first_2', 'last_2', null from dual union all
select 'first_3', 'last_3', null from dual union all
select 'first_4', 'last_4', null from dual union all  -- in A, NOT in B
select 'first_5', 'last_5', null from dual union all  -- in A, NOT in B
select 'first_6', 'last_6', null from dual ;          -- in A, NOT in B

-- enforce uniqueness of the APPIDs in tableA
alter table tableA 
add constraint appid_unique unique( appid ) ;

create table tableB (
  AppID number 
, Fst_nm varchar2( 100 )
, Lst_nm varchar2( 100 )
);

insert into tableB(appid, fst_nm, lst_nm )
select 1, 'first_1', 'last_1' from dual union all
select 2, 'first_2', 'last_2' from dual union all
select 3, 'first_3', 'last_3' from dual union all
select 7, 'first_7', 'last_7' from dual union all
select 8, 'first_8', 'last_8' from dual union all
select 9, 'first_9', 'last_9' from dual ;
```

The test tables contain ...

```
select * from tableA ;
    FST_NM    LST_NM    APPID 
__________ _________ ________ 
first_1    last_1             
first_2    last_2             
first_3    last_3             
first_4    last_4             
first_5    last_5             
first_6    last_6  

select * from tableB ;
   APPID     FST_NM    LST_NM 
________ __________ _________ 
       1 first_1    last_1    
       2 first_2    last_2    
       3 first_3    last_3    
       7 first_7    last_7    
       8 first_8    last_8    
       9 first_9    last_9
```

MERGE

```
merge into tableA A
using tableB B on ( A.fst_nm = B.fst_nm and A.lst_nm = B.lst_nm )  
when matched then
  update set A.appid = B.appid
when not matched then
  insert ( fst_nm, lst_nm, appid )
    values ( B.fst_nm, B.lst_nm, appid_seq.nextval )
;

6 rows merged.

-- data in tableA now:
SQL> select * from tableA ;
    FST_NM    LST_NM     APPID 
__________ _________ _________ 
first_1    last_1            1  -- updated
first_2    last_2            2  -- updated
first_3    last_3            3  -- updated 
first_4    last_4              
first_5    last_5              
first_6    last_6              
first_8    last_8       998003  -- inserted
first_7    last_7       998004  -- inserted 
first_9    last_9       998005  -- inserted
```

UPDATE

```
update tableA
set appid = appid_seq.nextval
where appid is null ;
-- 3 rows updated.

-- final result
SQL> select * from tableA ;
    FST_NM    LST_NM     APPID 
__________ _________ _________ 
first_1    last_1            1 
first_2    last_2            2 
first_3    last_3            3 
first_4    last_4       998006 
first_5    last_5       998007 
first_6    last_6       998008 
first_8    last_8       998003 
first_7    last_7       998004 
first_9    last_9       998005
```

Not quite sure: whether you will need the final UPDATE for your data or not.  If you consider using a SEQUENCE, you could also define a DEFAULT value for the APPID in tableA.  Then you don't need to write sequencename.nextval into the MERGE or UPDATE eg

```
-- add a DEFAULT value for the appids
alter table tableA modify appid default appid_seq.nextval ;

update tableA
set appid = DEFAULT
where appid is null ;
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38ed38fe502d5eb2da824e72da1d6530).